# How to stop activity inside the AsyncTask class

Tags: android, android-asynctask

> I tried to put finish() method to stop back stack.but it gave syntax error to me.how can I stop back stack.Thanks in advance.

```
 private class getNewMessages extends AsyncTask<ApiConnector, Long, JSONArray> {


            @Override
            protected JSONArray doInBackground(ApiConnector... params) {
                try {
                    JSONArray array = params[0].getMessage(name, password);
                    // String [] array=new String[10];

                    if (array.length() > 0) {
                        Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), bussiness.class);
                        nextScreen.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(nextScreen);

                    }
                }catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wrong Credintials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {


            }


        }
```

Comment: Does AsyncTask internal class of Activity? If yes: NameOfActivity.this.finish();

Comment: yes It is a internal class of service class.In side the service class I call intent.but your method did not work to me.

Comment: Internal of service class or internal of activity?

Comment: Internal of service class

Answer (score 2):

Shift your code to your onPostExecute callback

```
     @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
           if (result.length() > 0) {
                    Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), bussiness.class);
                    nextScreen.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(nextScreen);
                }

        }
```

Comment: sorry it also showing error."context can not resolve"

Comment: You have access to context within the service. Simply remove the context.

Comment: "You have access to context within the service. Simply remove the context." I did not get that

Answer (score 0):

Try using `(Activity)mContext).finish();` or `finish();`

Comment: startActivity(nextScreen);
finish();
"Can not resolve method finish()".

Comment: I need to stop back stack .but finish() method does not work for it.and I want to say Async task class is a internal class of service class.

Comment: So you want to stop Async task from Service class?Is that your requirement?

Comment: when startActivity(nextScreen) it goes to another UI.after that I click the back button I need to close the app.that is the thing.

Comment: Try  `this.finish();` and `ClassName.finish();`